# Can .ASP ViewModel have DTO collection as public members?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dto, n-layer

As an example:

I have a data transfer object mapped from my business entity.

I have a Controller, that calls business logic `handler` class, that returns `List<MyDTO> result`.

Can I have `List<MyDTO>` as a public member in my `ViewModel` so that I can load `List<MyDTO> result` into my `ViewModel`, and afterwards use `foreach` and so on from my `View`, and take data from List in ViewModel to show it in a View?

Or should DTO be used ONLY for transfer, not as a `ViewModel` public member?

Comment: Keep view models and DTOs separately to save maintenance issues in future. Use mapping libraries like auto mapper to map them in controller.

Comment: Thx. I was think the same way, just need some confrim.

Comment: You may, nothing can stop you from doing this. however as suggested if your DTO and viewModel look exactly the same then autoMapper can help save time.